# Vim ignores shiftwidth specified in .vimrc

Tags: vim

I am using Vim 7.3.154 cli on Linux Mint 12 "Lisa"(x64).

I prefer using a `tabstop` and `shiftwidth` of 2 columns.
My `.vimrc` has
`:set ts=2`
`:set sw=2`
to accomplish the same.

Whenever I open a new instance of Vim, `tabstop` value is retained, so existing tabs are rendered according to `.vimrc`. But somehow the `shiftwidth` value gets changed to 3. This results in 3 column indention while auto-indenting.
Running `:set sw=2` on the new instance of Vim fixes this issue.
Can anyone tell me why Vim is ignoring/changing `shiftwidth` value from `.vimrc`?

I tried disabling all plugins to no avail.

[Vim compiled options](http://pastebin.com/aejBXkAD)  |  [.vimrc](http://pastebin.com/jjqvNuwB)

Comment: Make sure that the files you're editing don't contain file specific settings. `:h modeline`

Comment: Also, set `nocompatible` at the beginning of your .vimrc file, it should be the absolute first thing.

Comment: Also, you really should check out this video regarding tabs and such: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tabs-and-spaces/ Here's my own solution to that: https://github.com/Greduan/dotfiles/blob/6cba02d63a12d3aa313ebe1f0787af55a4e76900/vim/vimrc.vim#L274-L278

Comment: @Eduan, thanks for your reply. The problem was indeed being caused by file specific settings - `php.vim` present in `plugin` directory.  
But, it still is unclear to me as to why Vim was loading `php.vim` for other filetypes too. Tt was not present in `pathogen` or `autoload` directories.

Comment: That's because it was in the `/plugin` directory. Anything in that directory gets loaded every time Vim is finished loading. Check this for more info: http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/42.html#vimplugin I will put up an answer so that this topic can be closed. :)

Comment: `:verbose set sw?` should tell you where the current setting was made.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer just summarizes what we discussed in the comments. :)

This is most likely caused by the fact that you have file specific settings enabled. Check `:h modeline` for more info on that. Make sure that those files you have the problems with don't have this line in them.

---

Instead of only setting `tabstop` and `shiftwidth` you should also setup a couple more settings regarding whitespace and tabs.

```
set noexpandtab " Make sure that every file uses real tabs, not spaces
set shiftround  " Round indent to multiple of 'shiftwidth'
set smartindent " Do smart indenting when starting a new line
set autoindent  " Copy indent from current line, over to the new line

" Set the tab width
let s:tabwidth=4
exec 'set tabstop='    .s:tabwidth
exec 'set shiftwidth=' .s:tabwidth
exec 'set softtabstop='.s:tabwidth
```

Check this video for some extra info: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tabs-and-spaces/

---

So this is the answer to the actual problem that you were able to solve. That `php.php` file was in the `/plugin` directory. That directory gets loaded once, each and every time Vim starts up. Check this: http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/42.html#vimplugin

If what you want is that file to load only on PHP files then you should put it in the `/ftplugin` folder: http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/42.html#vimftplugin

Read the documentation there, it should be a `.vim` file, in other words in this case it would be called `php.vim`.

What Pathogen or Vundle do is modify the runtimepath (`:h runtimepath`), nothing more, nothing less.

So you can now accept this answer, by clicking the little green arrow to the left of this answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info, especially the links.

Comment: @Jitesh No problem. :) Vim is full of documentation, and finding it is not always easy. So I'm glad I was able to help. :)

Comment: Reading it back this is definitely my best answer ever.

Comment: I couldn't get anything to work for me in my VIm. Ruby files were fine, but EVERY JS file I opened would do 4 spaces. Using this template and changing it to my specs worked beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

You can run:

```
verbose set shiftwidth ?
```

to check what is setting the value of shiftwidth. It might coming from a plugin. You can also choose to modify the value there.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30520892)